# How functional dependency imply multi valued dependency?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, database-theory, dependencies

I understand following informal definition of multi valued dependency:

> If multi valued dependency is α↠β, then whenever the tuples (a,b,c) and (a,d,e) exist in relation r, the tuples (a,b,e)  and (a,d,c) should also exist in r.

I also understand following formal definition:

> Let R be a relation schema and let α⊆R and β⊆R (subsets). The multivalued dependency α↠β holds on R if, in any legal relation r(R), for all pairs of tuples t1 and t2 in r such that t1[α]=t2[α], there exist tuples t3 and t4 in r such that
>   t1[α] = t2[α] = t3[α] = t4 [α]
>   t3[β] = t1[β]
>   t3[R-β] = t2[R-β]
>   t4[β] = t2[β]
>   t4[R-β] = t1[R-β]

For example,

> t1 = (a,b,c)
>   t2 = (a,d,e)
>   t3 = (a,b,e)
>   t4 = (a,d,c)
>   α = first attribute which is a in all t1,t2,t3,t4
>   β = second attribute
>   t1[α] = t2[α] = t3[α] = t4[α] = a
>   t3[β] = t1[β] = b
>   t3[R-β] = t2[R-β] = (a,e)
>   t4[β] = t2[β] = d
>   t4[R-β] = t1[R-β] = (a,c)

I also understand following definition of functional dependency:

> Given a relation R, a set of attributes X in R is said to functionally determine another set of attributes Y, also in R, (written X → Y) if, and only if, each X value in R is associated with precisely one Y value in R.

Also I came across following points which distinguishes FD and MVD:

- FD is equality generating dependency.
- MVD is tuple generating dependency.

Now I came across following property of MVDs [stated on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency#Properties):

> If α→β then α↠β

I dont how both definitions imply above. To be specific, definition of α→β is not tuple generating or in other words, it does not enforce (a,b,e) and (a,d,c) should exist, given (a,b,c) and (a,d,e) exist, right?

Comment: The standard technique to prove a claim about operator calls: Write formal versions of definitions & claim; replace calls in the claim by definitions with parameters replaced by arguments from calls; simplify to an evident truth. Here the claim is that the FD holding implies the MVD holding. Ditto for reasoning re "generating". PS A more ad hoc & sloppy proof for your claim: Suppose α→β. If (a,b,c) & (a,d,e) exist then, by definition of FD, b=d; hence (a,d,c) & (a,b,e) exist; hence α↠β. Observe that under α→β we can decompose to αβ & α(R-β), which is when α↠β with 1 b per a.

Comment: What is your question?--how to prove it, or, is your argument correct, or, what is a wrong step in your argument, or what? Your argument is too unclear to critique--Your phrasing is too sloppy & your argument steps are too large. Eg "α→β is not tuple generating" & "it does not enforce (a,b,e)" use technical terms wrongly, so are unintelligible, when clear will be unjustified. Eg it's not clear why the RHS is the LHS "in other words". Eg Just because a certain kind of dependency is a certain kind of "Xing" doesn't mean that a certain 1 of the 1st kind can't also be of the 2nd kind.